# puppeteer insert variable into page.$eval

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to insert a variable into an input field ...
according to puppeeteer docs this how you do it :[Documentaion](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)
page.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])

```
let VARIABLE = "01.01.2020"
await page.$eval("input[name=date]", el => (el.value = VARIABLE));
```

Im trying to set the el.value to a variable of mine...
Getting undefined error .. how can I pass my variable to el.value ? ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this:

```js
await page.$eval('input[name="date"]', (el, value) => el.value = value, VARIABLE);
```

Comment: I dont understand that syntax el.value = value, VARIABLE
but it does work ;) ... never did this kind of thing

Comment: @balui the passed function to `$eval` executes in the page context which is different from nodejs (puppeteer) so it is blind to what VARIABLE is. you need to pass the VARIABLE to the `$eval` function, and the way you do it is this way.

Comment: I see . Can you link me to a ressource / documentation
for this particular thing ?  Im not sure what to look for .. otehrwise I would google myself xD

If not its fine . ty for help

Comment: @balui the puppeteer docs covers everything you need. read the third bullet point [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)

Comment: I meant that bit with el.value = value, VARIABLE

I just never learned or heard of this syntax .. Where you put a comma to replace the current value.

So it confused me ... that stuff is not in the docs either? So idk how you came up with this solution ;) ... its like some basic js I never heard of lol... xD

Comment: @balui maybe putting brackets makes it less confusing: `$eval(selector, (el, value) => { el.value = value }, VARIABLE)`, that `,` is a separator for arguments passing to `$eval`: 1) the selector, 2) the function, and 3) function's arguments.

Comment: case closed.. I was confused of this concept of comma seperators ... :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use page.type like so,

```
const VARIABLE = "01.01.2020"
await page.type('input[name=date]',VARIABLE);
```

You can refer to the thread for more info - https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options

Comment: im using page.type for the input fields that have no prior text.
The date field .. has always preset text so im trying to use eval
to manipulate the dom.